# Add Custom field to exist contact

Tags: android

I am trying to add custom field to raw contact id , im using this:

```
public static final String MIMETYPE="vnd.android.cursor.item/favsong";

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id);
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE);
values.put(Data.DATA1, "MyFavSong");
Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

the insert always return OK on all of my contacts but after trying to get the value (by query the mime type and the raw contact id) i can see that it doesnt exist on some of my contacts, why?

any chance that it is related some how to the fact the my contacts belongs to more then one account (sometimes Linkedin ,facebook, google and etc..)

tnx